# What day of the German church year would be "Festo Pascha II"?

Tags: germany, church-records, latin, protestant-church

I'm trying to figure out the proclamation dates for a marriage that took place on April 19 of 1836.  The dates are given using the church dates, which seems to have been normal practice for around 50 years in this particular church.  However, most of them use German names, whereas in this case, I think it's using Latin names for the dates?  Generally, I find https://kirchenkalender.com/ to be quite helpful, but in this case, I'm drawing a blank.

[image]

There's almost nothing on Google for "Festo Pacha".  Based off https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter, I'm guessing that Festo Pacha might be Easter Sunday, placing this somewhere around:

[image: English translated kirchenkalender for 1836]

However, I have very little expertise with the litergical calender.  Would anyone have a better idea which three Sundays this indicated?  In case it makes a difference, this was from a German Protestant church, not a Catholic church.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed (church) latin. The days are, referring to your list:

- Festo Pascha, "Easter festival" -> Easter Sunday
- Dom. Quasim. -> White Sunday
- Dom. Miseric. -> 2nd Sunday after Easter

As for the numerals, I'm not sure. My guess is that this is the service the proclamation was made in (with several services on each day).